# Tableau how to show labels for both total and running total

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau, in my simple example below

[image]

It shows sales by year and quarter, and also a running total for each year. I know how to create running total. My question is how to create the labels (Sales Total, Running Total)?

The example is from here: It's a simple illustration without step by step guide.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/windows/en-us/help.htm#calculations_tablecalculations_definebasic_runningtotal.html%3FTocPath%3DAdvanced%2520Analysis%7CCalculations%7CTable%2520Calculations%7CDefining%2520Basic%2520Table%2520Calculations%7C_____6

I tried to add Measure Names to Rows and only got this. The label displays 'No Measure value'. But if I add Measure Values to Marks, it shows all measures with labels but not the running total.

[image]

Comment: hmm.. Try clicking on `show me` then choose `Text tables` (The first chart  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have your measures on the text shelf, instead of measure values. So Measure Names shows "No Measure Value".

First step, try to reproduce the following:
[image]

Then you can provide an alias for each measure name (such as by right clicking on the long names and choosing "Edit Alias") to make the measure names more readable like:
[image]

Comment: I finally figured it out, the problem is I didn't create a calculated field for the running total. When I drag Measure values to Text mark it shows Sum(sales) and other measures, I then click the sum(sales) and choose quick table calculation and running total. I then  delete the other measures, this will never work. I have to add the running total calculated field.

Comment: Look at the example screenshot in this answer. That shows you can solve the problem without creating a calculated field. You just can't put the exact same measure on the Measure Values shelf twice. If you first turn one SUM(Sales) into a table calculation, then you can drop a second SUM(Sales) to follow.

Comment: Thanks, I got it right without adding a calculated field. My mistake was to add second Sum(sales) on the Text Mark, instead I should add it under Measure Values pane.